# Authorize dialog appears twice when login to facebook android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

i am new in `facebook` development. i want to `login` to `facebook` and allow user to allow my app to publish photos and stuff. but when user `login` successfully he is shown authorization dialog twice.here is my code

```
Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

            // callback when session changes state
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                    Exception exception) {

                if (session.isOpened()) {
                    Log.d("", "usman: session is opened");
                    // make request to the /me API

                    Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                            new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                                // callback after Graph API response with
                                // user
                                // object
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                        Response response) {
                                    Log.d("", "onCompleted called");
                                    if (user != null) {
                                        // TextView welcome = (TextView)
                                        // findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                                        Log.d(MyConstants.TAG,
                                                "facebook Hello : "
                                                        + user.getName() + "!");

                                        publishStory();
                                        //isShared = true;

                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(
                                                getApplicationContext(),
                                                "Unable to Post,Try Again later",
                                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                } else {
                    Log.d("", "usman: Session is not open");
                }
            }
        });

private void publishStory() {
        Log.d("", "usman: in publishStory");
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

        if (session != null) {

            // Check for publish permissions
            List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
            if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
                pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
                Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                        this, PERMISSIONS);
                session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
                return;
            }

            FileInputStream fis = null;
            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(fileImage);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

            Bundle postParams = new Bundle();

            postParams.putString("name", "London For Less Postcard");
            postParams.putString("caption",
                    "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
            postParams
                    .putString(
                            "description",
                            "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");

            postParams.putByteArray("picture", data);

            Request.Callback callback = new Request.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    JSONObject graphResponse = response.getGraphObject()
                            .getInnerJSONObject();
                    String postId = null;
                    try {
                        postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.i("FB", "JSON error " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                    FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                    if (error != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(
                                SendPostCardActivity.this
                                        .getApplicationContext(),
                                error.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                        Log.d("", "usman: Error");
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(
                                SendPostCardActivity.this
                                        .getApplicationContext(),
                                "Posted on facebook wall successfully",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.d("", "usman: Finish");
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            };

            Request request = new Request(session, "me/photos", postParams,
                    HttpMethod.POST, callback);

            RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
            task.execute();
        }

    }
```

Comment: From your code, this seems like the expected outcome. First you call openActiveSession, which will show the auth dialog. Then, after you get the initial permissions, you call publishStory, which will request new publish permissions, and it will show the auth dialog again.

Answer (score 1):

For me also Facebook login dialog box was shown twice when I click "login" with Facebook button.

I just changed Facebook default button and used normal button, with Facebook button background, now the login page is shown only once.

Facebook default button shows login page for normal and publish permission. I don't know the details but this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null ){
        if (!AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getPermissions().contains("publish_actions")){
            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but for the first time it will show two two logins right, one with normal permissions and other with publish permissions